# Vertical spacing for two consecutive figure environments

Tags: spacing, floats, positioning, vertical-alignment

I think I'm not going to solve my problem with the Floats and positioning of figures. I have 4 diagramms and I need to place them on two pages and at the end of the second page the caption for all 4 figures. So two figures on each page. For the the diagramms on the second page I need to place the upper image near to the top because I need some place for the caption. On the page before I need both figures to be centered in the middle with some spacing between them. So this is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[c]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{45.pdf}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[c]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{46.pdf}
\end{figure}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{47.pdf}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,skip=0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{48.pdf}
\caption{Konzentrationsprofile von Al, Re, Ta und W entlang der <110>-Richtung in der UC. }
\end{figure}
```

The problem for the secong page was solved, but the figures on the first page were also forced to the top which I don't want!

Comment: There exists no `[c]` float placement specifier.

Comment: Using the figure environment 4 times will give you 4 figure numbers, even though you only want one caption.  Is that what you want?  Or (a) - (d) with a single caption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear how flexible you are, but here is what I suggest.  It uses one figure number, repeating the caption on both pages (with a (continued) label on the second page.  It refers to sub-figures (a) through (d) (but doesn't use the subfigures package).  There is a 9pt gap between the bottom of the graphic and the (a) through (d) labels, and a 1cm gap between subfigures, all of which can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\stackunder[1cm]%
  {\stackunder[9pt]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3in]{45.pdf}}{(a)}}
  {\stackunder[9pt]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3in]{46.pdf}}{(b)}}%
\caption{Konzentrationsprofile von (a) Al, (b) Re, (c) Ta und 
  (d) W entlang der <110>-Richtung in der UC. }
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\stackunder[1cm]%
  {\stackunder[9pt]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3in]{47.pdf}}{(c)}}
  {\stackunder[9pt]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=3in]{48.pdf}}{(d)}}%
\caption{(continued) Konzentrationsprofile von (a) Al, (b) Re, (c) Ta und 
  (d) W entlang der <110>-Richtung in der UC. }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and a zoom (obviously, I don't have the right encoding, but that's not fixable):

[image]