# Arrange subfigure according to the text

Tags: floats, page-breaking, subfloats, text-manipulation

I have a little issue.
I have a figure made by 5 subifgures. They fill perfectly a page. 
The problem is that, when I have some lines of text before the image, the figure goes to the next page without "splitting", so I have a page with only a few lines and, in the other page, my figure, and it's not so pleasant to see.

So I would like to have, for example, a few lines then two subfigures and the other 3 subfigures in the other page and so on. According to the white space.

I searched a bit for similar questions, but I didn't find a similar problem.

Thanks in adivce.

Comment: Here's one approach: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122977/vertical-spacing-for-two-consecutive-figure-environments/122991#122991.  It involves using two separate figure environments, and resetting counters to make it count as a single figure.

Comment: Can you add a [minimmal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) showing which relevant packages (subfig,subcaption) you are using? do you know about `continuedfloat`? Remember, if a part is on the other page, you need to have 2 caption (one on each page).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Tomorrow I'll try your solutions. If i "fail" I'll give you more details.