# Split "include graphics" on two pages but keep same Figure number

Tags: graphics

In my MWE below, I originally had the figures on one page, but then as I added more text, it became apparent that I had to split the figures across two pages.  I wanted to keep the same Figure number for both figures (Figure 1). Is the best practice to use the `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1}` command?  Will I have a problem if I then try to reference part A and part B Figures in the document?  Thanks for your help.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{book}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=13cm,height=7cm]{scratch.png}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\label{fig1_ptA}
\caption{This is the first figure.}
\end{figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=13cm,height=7cm]{scratch.png}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\label{fig1_ptB}
\caption{This is the first figure (continued).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See, maybe, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274934/caption-spreading-over-two-pages

Comment: `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` between the two figures, perhaps? But that's not really robust enough, in case even more text results in the two parts of the figure ending up on the same page. I think personally, I'd be tempted to reach for the subfigure package and make figure 1a and 1b. It seems the least hacky solution.

Comment: do as Harald says. If you use `\renewcommand\thefigure{1} then it will be hard to regain the normal numbering afterwards

Comment: With the `caption` package, the use of `\caption[full toc caption]{caption part A}` and `\caption*{caption part B}` might achieve what you desire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `caption` for such cases define macro `\ContinuedFloat`. To the float, which is continuation of the previous one, you only need add this macro after `begin{figure}`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{book}
\usepackage[draft]{pgf}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{float} % <-- not used
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{scratch.png}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\caption{This is the first figure.} 
\label{fig1_ptA}    % <-- had to be after caption
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}[!t]
\ContinuedFloat     % <--- added
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{scratch.png}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\caption{This is the first figure (continued).}
\label{fig1_ptB}    % <-- had to be after caption
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

See Fig.~\ref{fig1_ptA} on page \pageref{fig1_ptA} and Fig.~\ref{fig1_ptB}  on page \pageref{fig1_ptB} \dots

\end{document}
```